# Meltano: tag-postgres to target-postgres: data type such as uuid is converted to varchar

Tags: postgresql, meltano

I'm actually working on a Meltano project where I have to extract data from one postgres database and load to the final warehouse (also a postgres database) using "Key-based Incremental Replication".

After the loading process of meltano, all table with columns of type `uuid` from the "tap-postgres" are changed to `varchar` in the target.
Could someone help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singer taps rarely capture "rich" string types such as `uuid`, and they output simple `{"type": "string"}` types without any additional metadata. Furthermore, Singer usually only supports JSONSchema Draft 4, so `{"type": "string", "format": "uuid"}` would not even be supported by most taps and targets.

Since Singer is an ELT analytics framework and in that context a `uuid` column type is not different in any meaningful way from a `varchar`, this is hardly an issue for most people.

If you need to replicate a database with that level of detail you may be better served by a different solution for database backup/replication.

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation!
Could you recommend me a better solution with this level of detail for database backup/replication?

Comment: Streaming replication would do that for you: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html

Most cloud providers offer this with their managed RDBMS, but it's not impossible to set for on-premises deployments too.